# Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

I was given a take home problem set to prepare for my upcoming final and was really hoping I could get some help.

In the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the normal Euclidean norm), consider the subspace $S$ consisting of all vectors $(x, y)$ such that $x + y = 0$, and the linear functional $f$ defined on $S$ by $f(x, y) = x + y$.

Find $\|f\|$, and find an extension of $f$ to a linear functional $g$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f$ and g agree on S and $\|f\| = \|g\|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f=0$ on $S$ by definition of $S$, we have $\|f\|=0$.

There is exactly one extension $g$ of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which has $\|g\|=\|f\|=0$. That's 
$$
g:(x,y)\longmapsto 0
$$
the null functional.

Note: this is a slightly silly exercise...